# In bash, should I unset a local variable inside a function?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Should I unset my local variables at the end of a function in a bash script? 
As an example, the following function:

```
square()
{
  local var=$1
  (( var = var * var ))
  echo $var
  ## should I unset $var here??
}
```

Just curious about best practices, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you weren't using the `local` command, then you would want to unset the variable before leaving the function to avoid polluting the global namespace.

```
square () {
    var=$1    # var is global, and could be used after square returns
    (( var = var * var ))
    echo $var
    unset var  # Remove it from the global namespace
}
```

The problem with that approach is that `square` doesn't know if it actually *created* `var` in the first place. It may have overwritten and ultimately unset a global variable that was in use before `square` was called.

Using `local`, you are guaranteed to create a *new* variable that is only visible inside the function. If there were a global `var`, it's value is ignored for the duration of the function. When the function exits, the local `var` is discarded, and the global `var` (if any) can be used as before.

```
$ var=3
$ echo $var
3
$ square 9
81
$ echo $var
3
```

Answer (score 4):

If that comment `## should I unset $var here??` is the end of your subroutine, you would not need to unset it, because it would go out of scope right after that anyway.